# Changing android camera params after startPreview()

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, google-gdk, android-hardware

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28381143/change-android-cameras-iso-value-after-startpreview), I'm trying to change parameters of the android camera after calling `startPreview()`. I'm processing video input frame by frame from the preview and need to adjust exposure settings in real time. `lock()` doesn't seem to be helpful and stopping the preview doesn't work at frame rate. However, just like the linked question has pointed out, once `startPreview()` is called, none of the param changes seem to go through to the camera.

In case it's relevant, I'm doing this on Google Glass... but that shouldn't make a difference.